# adding Image to page without using source

Tags: html

i need add an image to HTML page then I need to send this page via fax.
**i can not use the attribute "src"** Any ideas how can I do it? Maybe convert the image to byte array and then insert it to the html page?

Comment: We do not know what the limitations of your unspecified fax software are so this isn't really answerable.

Comment: well, to send the page via the fax i just put the page in some folder and that's all.

Comment: so there is no limitations except for: can not using source.

Comment: There *are* other limitations. You might not have encountered them, but they will exist.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use a "[data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme)".

**[EDIT]** If you can't use the `src` attribute, then you're doomed. There are other ways to add an image to a HTML page like using a `div` with `background-image` but that image won't make it to the printer (and hence not onto a fax).

Comment: No, that would go in the src attribute, which can't be used.

Comment: Never heard of that, but I like it.  +1 for teaching me something new!

Answer (score 0):

Why can you not use the `src` attribute?  Does the fax software somehow internally render the HTML without images and thus ignore it?  If that or something similar is the case then you're better off trying to work around it than to try to trick it with some strange byte manipulation.

Can the fax software accept the entire page as one big image?  You can add the image to the HTML as you would any other image in a web page, then use something like [FireShot](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5648/) for Firefox to capture the entire rendered page into a single image (or split up by pages, etc.) and fax that.